# How to solve this HTML input field problem?

Tags: html, forms, input

I have the following problem. I made an input form with a height of 5vh (more than default) and when I want to type something inside, typing cursor is centered in the input field. I want to put it at the start of the input field.

Now is like this

[image: Now is like this]

I want this

[image: I want this]

Comment: You'll need to post a [mcve] in your question. Please see [ask]

Comment: Please provide the HTML and CSS necessary to reproduce your issue. You can likely use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>`  in the editor toolbar) to help others.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you should make that a `<textarea>` tag with the "resize" to be none, like this:

```
`<textarea placeholder="Your message" style="height:7vh; resize:none;"></textarea>`
```

I hope this helped..

Comment: Please read [answer], where it says, "Answer well-asked questions".